# masm - нахождение общих символов в двух строках

Tags: ассемблер, masm32, masm

Из консоли считываются две строки. Необходимо вывести символы, которые принадлежат обеим строкам. Например,

```
Input: 123qwe
       ytrewq
Output: qwe (порядок вывода символов может быть любой)
```

Я только начинаю учить ассемблер, возможно, есть какой-то более простой и правильный способ, но логика моей программы выглядит примерно так:

Есть один цикл, который проходит по всем символам первой строки, и есть вложенный в него цикл, который проходит по всем символам второй строки. Если есть два одинаковых символа, то добавить их в конец результирующей строки.

```
include \masm32\include\masm32rt.inc  

.data
    scanForm    db      "%s",0
    printForm   db      "%s",0
       lenA        dd        0,0
       lenB        dd        0,0
       count       dd        0
       i       dd        0
       a       dd   0,0
       b       dd   0,0
.data?
        _in dd ?

    _out         dd   ?
.code
start:

        invoke      crt_scanf, offset scanForm, offset a  
        call _strlen 
        mov lenA, eax


        invoke      crt_scanf, offset scanForm, offset b
        ;call _strlen 
        ;mov lenB, eax
        mov eax, lenA
        mov lenB, eax


        printf ("%d\n",lenA)
        printf ("%d\n",lenB)

        mov ecx, lenA
        _c1:
            mov eax, lenB
            mov count, eax
            _c2:

                mov eax, count
                mov ebx, lenA
                ;printf ("%c %c\n",[a+ebx-1],[b+eax-1] )
                mov edx, [a+ebx-1]
                mov ecx, [b+eax-1] 
                .if edx == ecx
                    ;printf ("%c",a[ebx-1])
                    mov ebx, i
                    mov [_out+ebx], ecx
                    inc i
                .endif

                mov ecx, [count]
                dec count
            loop _c2

            mov ecx, lenA
            dec lenA

        loop _c1

        lea eax, _out
        printf ("%s\n",eax)

    inkey "Enter any key to continue..."
    call ExitProcess

        _strlen:
            mov edi,offset a
            mov eax, 0
            f1:
                inc eax
                cmp byte ptr[eax+edi],0
            jnz f1
            ret
end start
```

У меня возникло три проблемы:

1. Как посчитать длину второй строки, с помощью моей функции _strlen? (Возможно, её нужно как-то модифицировать)
2. У меня не работает условный оператор, хотя символы перебираются правильно.
3. Как добавлять в результат только те символы, которых ещё нет

Ну 1 и 3 проблемы через какие-то костыли я может и смогу сам решить, а вот основная проблема с условным оператором.

Буду рад, если дадите какие-то корректировки по остальному коду (если типа можно было бы написать что-то лучше)

Comment: какие то странные у вас "символы". для начала уточните в какой кодировке входная строка. от этого зависит размер символа в байтах. для самого простого случая можно считать символ размером один байт ... но вы то делаете `mov edx, [a+ebx-1]` а регистры E** размером 32 бита, т.е. 4 байта, так что вы загружаете в регистр и пытаетесь сравнивать сразу по 4 символа ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> логика моей программы выглядит примерно так:
>
> Есть один цикл, который проходит по всем символам первой строки, и есть вложенный в него цикл, который проходит по всем символам второй строки. Если есть два одинаковых символа, то добавить их в конец результирующей строки.

Мало того, что скучно, так ещё и при повторении символов в строках в итоговой строке будут дубликаты. Некрасиво, и формально не соответствует заданию.

Предлагаю следующий подход.

1. Резервируете таблицу-массив в 256 байт и обнуляете их.
2. Проходите по первой строке и, используя код символа как индекс, устанавливаете первый бит соотв. байта массива простым `OR byte ptr [BP+AX], 1`
3. Аналогично проходите по второй строке, но устанавливаете второй бит аналогичным `OR byte ptr [BP+AX], 2`
4. Проходите по массиву, сравнивая элементы с 3 (1 OR 2), и выводите символы с кодом, равным индексу прошедшего проверку элемента.

Comment: - создаем в памяти 2 (два) 256 битный ключ / вынимаем первый символ из первой строки в ecx / отделяем от него старшую часть двойным сдвигом в eax / делаем биттест первого ключа используя eax как base, в eax как номер бита / узнаем был ли символ уже использован / проходим вторую строку ищем совпадения / делаем пометку во втором ключе / продолжаем скан первой строки / выводим все символы отмеченные во втором ключе